# PHP Serialization Alternative

Tags: php, optimization, serialization

I'm looking for a good cache key for APC that represents some complied information about an object, using the "object" as the key.  I have a compilation method that does something like this:

```
function compile(Obj $obj)
{
    if ($this->cache)
    {
        $cachekey = serialize($obj);

        if ($data = $this->cache->get($obj))
        {
            return $data
        }
    }

    // compute result here

    if ($this->cache)
    {
        $this->cache->set($cachekey, $result);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

If it's not obvious, `$this->cache` is an implementation of an interface with the methods `get` and `set`.

Is there a quicker alternative to creating a key that's unique to *some* of the properties of this object?  I can extract the relevant bits out, but then they are still arrays, which would have the same problem with serialization that I had with the objects in the first place.

Serialize works, from a "correctness" position, but it seems wasteful (both in size of outputted key, and in computational complexity).

EDIT: I would also like to add, if it's not obvious, that I will *not* be needing to unserialize this object.  My verbatim code for the current cache key is actually:

`$cachekey = 'compile.' . sha1(serialize($obj));`.

EDIT 2: The object I'm working with has the following definition:

```
class Route
{
    protected $pattern;
    protected $defaults = array();
    protected $requirements = array();
}
```

`Pattern` and `requirements` are the values of the object that will change the output of this method, therefore a hash of these values must be present in the cache key.

Also, someone suggested uniqid(), which would defeat the purpose of a general cache lookup key, as you could not reliably regenerate the same ID from the same information.

EDIT 3: I guess I'm not giving enough context.  Here's a link to the code so far:

https://github.com/efritz/minuet/blob/master/src/Minuet/Routing/Router.php#L160

I guess I'm really only trying to avoid expensive calls to serialize (and I guess sha1, which is also a bit expensive).  It's possible that the best I can do is try to reduce the size of what I'm serializing...

Comment: what's wrong with "computational complexity"?

Comment: It's running more cycles than I actually need ;)  serialize is currently the only method that's taking more time than apc_fetch itself, when there's a cache hit.

Comment: So you want to retrieve a data item based on the value of that data item, or alternatively store the data item? This makes no sense - in order to retrieve the value you must already know what it is!

Comment: I'm doing additional processing to the item.  I'm actually generating a regex for a URL route matcher, which I want to store based on pattern and regex requirements, but don't want to generate until it's needed the first time.

Comment: Wouldn't the whole thing be much more simple if `Obj` had a unique id?

Comment: Which would be regenerated how?  I'm not storing the route _objects_ between requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it might be to generate a key based simply from the values you use to compute the result..

Here is a **rough** example.

```
function compile(Obj $obj)
{
    if ($this->cache)
    {
        $cachekey = 'Obj-result-' . sha1($obj->pattern . '-' . serialize($obj->requirements));
        // You could even try print_r($obj->requirements, true)
        // or even json_encode($obj->requirements)
        // or implode('-', $obj->requirements)
        // Can't say for sure which is slowest, or fastest.
        if ($data = $this->cache->get($cachekey))
        {
            return $data
        }
    }

    // compute result here
    $result = $obj->x + $obj->y; // irrelevant, and from original answer.

    if ($this->cache)
    {
        $this->cache->set($cachekey, $result);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Since you use an array of data, you'd still need to turn it into something that makes sense as a key.. However this way you're now only serializing a part of the object, rather then the whole thing. See how it goes. :)

Comment: But $obj->x and $obj->y would actually be array structures, which would then require serialization....  I'll make an edit about the object structure.

Comment: It appears in your example $pattern isn't an array. Anyways, I updated my answer.

Comment: This is the best solution so far ~~

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the `spl_object_hash` function that seems to fit perfectly for your needs.

Comment: Does this function keep consistent hashes between requests?

Comment: "A string that is unique for each currently existing object and is always the same for each object." Look at the comments on the PHP manual's page.

Comment: "Note that the contents (properties) of the object are NOT hashed by the function, merely its internal handle and handler table pointer."  Each request that comes in may have a different starting point on the stack.  I'm printing an object hash of one of the objects and it changes on EVERY request.  This doesn't work between requests.

Comment: Also, object hashes can be re-used when an object is destroyed, if it occupies that same place in memory afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is very hard to suggest any viable solution without knowing how the whole system works.

But, Why don't you just simply add a `cache_key` property with a `uniqid()` value in your object?

Comment: I don't understand how a random and non-reproducible fits into this context.  See my edit above for more information on the object.

Comment: You didn't get me right. I know `uniqid()` is non-reproducible. What I meant was add that id with each object as a signature. And use that as a primary key of your object. you can map it with your related object like [user1 - obj12328018230]. Sorry that you get it wrong and again sorry if you sill can't get it.

Comment: I get it now, but I'm not storing objects in a database.  Check my edit for a link.